# Default encoding in Geronimo with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, encoding, geronimo

I'm looking for functional way to set default character encoding for HTTP responses for Geronimo 3 with Tomcat. It seems there is a lot of work-arounds, but not any way to easily set some property in some file like in case of Apache Httpd. (Apache Httpd has `AddDefaultCharset` used for all responses.) I've tried add attributes `useBodyEncodingForURI` and `URIEncoding` to `<connector>` elements in `var/catalina/server.xml`.

```
<Connector name="TomcatWebConnector"
    port="${HTTPPort + PortOffset}"
    address="${ServerHostname}"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="${HTTPSPort + PortOffset}"
    useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    executor="DefaultThreadPool"/>
```

But it does not work. I still get header `Content-Type text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1` in response. Another solution is to programaticaly change headers in application (e.g. via filter or valve), but I don't find it *systemic*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned to my question I had asked two months ago. I know now that the solution using a filter is not any workaround, but common way. Just write a filter class:

```
package eu.barbucha.tests;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class EncodingSettingFilter implements Filter {
    private final String enc = "utf-8";

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain fc)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding(enc);
        resp.setCharacterEncoding(enc);
        fc.doFilter(request, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

And assign the filter with all URIs in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file:

```
<filter>
    <description>Filter setting encoding</description>
    <filter-name>enc-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>eu.barbucha.tests.EncodingSettingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>enc-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

That's all.